# how to print log_in and log_out time from one table without any user id and count of "on" in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have this i/p table

| event_time | status |
| --- | --- |
| 10:01 | on |
| 10:02 | on |
| 10:03 | on |
| 10:04 | off |
| 10:07 | on |
| 10:08 | on |
| 10:09 | off |
| 10:11 | on |
| 10:12 | off |

I want this output

| login | logout | count_of_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:01 | 10:04 | 3 |
| 10:07 | 10:09 | 2 |
| 10:11 | 10:12 | 1 |

i tried with cases but not helping

Comment: This is tagged both MySQL and Oracle. Is that intentional or by accident? What product are you using? (BOTH?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY event_time
  MEASURES
    FIRST(event_time)       AS login_time,
    LAST(event_time)        AS logout_time,
    COUNT(on_status.status) AS count_of_on
  PATTERN (on_status+ (off_status | $))
  DEFINE
    on_status AS status  = 'on',
    off_status AS status = 'off'
)
```

Or, in both MySQL and Oracle, you can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT MIN(event_time) AS login_time,
       MAX(next_time)  AS logout_time,
       COUNT(*)        AS count_of_on
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(event_time, 1, event_time) OVER (ORDER BY event_time)
           AS next_time,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_time)
           - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY event_time) AS grp
  FROM   table_name t
) t
WHERE  status = 'on'
GROUP BY grp;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (event_time, status) AS
SELECT '10:01', 'on'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:02', 'on'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:03', 'on'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:04', 'off' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:07', 'on'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:08', 'on'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:09', 'off' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:11', 'on'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10:12', 'off' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | LOGIN_TIME | LOGOUT_TIME | COUNT_OF_ON |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10:01 | 10:04 | 3 |
> | 10:07 | 10:09 | 2 |
> | 10:11 | 10:12 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=294ca393ad8f52b6262fc1c7f52e0492) [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0df7b930e1e5d9ef01206ad69cb4dcd0)*

Comment: The logout time is the time of the OFF row, not the time of the last ON row. (It makes sense logically). The OP's desired output shows as much. The solution can be modified easily to accommodate - add the first OFF row to the PATTERN.

Comment: In the analytic functions solution (but not in the match_recognize solution), if the last row is an ON row, you are also showing it as the "logout" event. Probably best to leave the "logout" time as NULL in that case, as the match_recognize solution does; in any case, it's a good question for the OP.

Comment: @mathguy In the case when the last row is `on`, they both show the value of the last row but it is easy enough to change both to show `NULL`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bf7e3b0fc189deca78e8327562b1ff89) gives examples of both.